# CSS width, should I use max width with percent or by pixel

Tags: css

Let's say I have a container, and I want it to be 1200px wide on large screens, and on screens that are <= 1200px, I want it to take all of the window's width. 
The question is - which CSS syntax is a better practice, and **why?**

1)

```css
  .container {
      width: 1200px;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container" style="border: 5px solid magenta; background-color: black; color: white; padding: 1em;">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, ea, nemo. Sequi saepe aut eius voluptatum doloribus! Aliquam corporis vitae eveniet, sapiente eos similique voluptatum molestiae, nostrum animi facere, voluptatibus nemo maxime voluptas ipsum atque! Molestias obcaecati totam pariatur vel.
</div>
```

2)

```css
.container {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 1200px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container" style="border: 5px solid cyan; background-color: black; color: white; padding: 1em;">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, ea, nemo. Sequi saepe aut eius voluptatum doloribus! Aliquam corporis vitae eveniet, sapiente eos similique voluptatum molestiae, nostrum animi facere, voluptatibus nemo maxime voluptas ipsum atque! Molestias obcaecati totam pariatur vel.
</div>
```

I checked on various browsers and devices, both of the CSS options worked good.

Comment: I'd say it's just a matter of taste. I would use the second variant.

Comment: I would use the second option because it is more readable IMO, but i think you can use whatever you prefer..

Comment: I would use also the second because it describe  the definition of max-width:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-width.asp